# Probability of a string of bits having same values in the first $k$ symbols.

Tags: probability

Imagine you are sent a string of $n$ bits. The probability of sending a $0$ and a $1$ are equal, $p = q = 1/2$. Supposing there is no errors in the delivery of the signal, how would you calculate the probability that the string have the same type of symbols in the first $k$ digits?

I've started with
$$
P(X = k) = \\ \; \\\underbrace{P(\underbrace{1 \cap 1 \cap \dots \cap 1}_\textrm{k}  \; \underbrace{\cap \dots \cap 0 \cap 0}_\textrm{n-k}) + P(1 \cap1 \cap 1 \cap \dots \cap 0 \cap 1) + \dots}_\textrm{$2^{n - k}$ times} \\ \; \\ \underbrace{P(\underbrace{0 \cap 0 \cap  \dots \cap 0}_\textrm{k}  \; \underbrace{\cap \dots \cap 0 \cap 0}_\textrm{n-k}) + P(0 \cap 0 \cap 0 \cap \dots \cap 0 \cap 1) + \dots}_\textrm{$2^{n - k}$ times}
$$
The first $k$ bits must be the same, and there exits $2^{n - k}$, permutations of the rest elements, so:

$$
P(X = k) = 2^{n - k}P(1)^k \Pi_{n - k} + 2^{n - k}P(0)^k \Pi_{n - k} 
$$
where $P(0) = p = q = P(1)$ and $\Pi_{m}$ is the probability of the $m$-th permutation.
$$
P(X = k) = 2^{n - k + 1}p^k\Pi_{n - k}
$$
Now our job is to find $\Pi_{n - k}$. But is easy, because the probabilites of $1$ and $0$ are the same and we don't bother about how many ones or zeros we obtain after the first $k$ ones:
$$\Pi_{n - k} = p^{n - k}$$
Finally:
$$
P(X = k) = 2^{n - k + 1}p^n
$$
Is this right? Why in this case order matters when taking into account the different permutations? Could you model this same behaviour with a binomial distribution?

Comment: I believe that (i) $n$ does not enter into the equation as the question asks only for the **first k** bits (ii) See also my comment under Ethan Bolker's answer explaining answer of $\frac12^{n-1}$

Comment: I've posted a question on your answer, showing that my equation is the same as you pointed out. But I do not know if the reasoning is right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is incorrect, and you don't have to go through such a tortorous route in any case.

All you are asked is that the first *k* bits are the same, you aren't bothered about the rest of the string.

The first bit can be anything ($0\;or\;1)$, and the probability that succeedding bits are the same as the first is $\frac12$ for each suceeding  bit,

Thus by the Multiplication Law, $P(X=k) = (\frac12)^{k-1}$

Comment: $P(X = k) = 2^{n-k+1}p^n = 2^{n-k+1}2^{-n} = 2^{1 - k} = (1/2)^{(k - 1)}$ Is coincidence, or it is wrong? I mean, is my reasoning ok? I just don't know.

Answer (score 1):

All $2^n$ bit strings of any particular length are equally likely. The chance that any string of length at least $n$ begins with a particular string of $k$ bits is $2^{-k}$ since all initial strings are equally likely. So that's the probability that two strings of length $n$ start the same way.

You can see that easily when $k=1$. Half the strings start with $0$, half with $1$. The probability that two coin tosses agree is $1/2$.

If this does not answer the question then (I think) the question is unclear and should be edited. (Don't try to fix it in comments).

Comment: Half the strings start with $1$, half with $0$ with probability $\frac12$ each,  then the probability should be $\frac12*\frac12* 2^{n-1} + \frac12*\frac12*2^{n-1} = \frac12^{n-1}$

Comment: @trueblueanil I don't think so. In the case $n=1$ your comment implies two strings match their first element with probability $(1/2)^0 = 1$. Check your algebra.

Comment: You get 1 because the probability of the first bit being either 0 or 1 is 1. No?

Comment: @ÁlvaroRodrigo That's true, but not relevant for this question, which asks if two independent choices of a string will start with the same bit. That probability is $1/2$. The same as the probability of two heads or two tails in two fair coin flips.

Comment: If you pick up a string of one bit (because $n$ does not influence the result), and you want them to have the first $k$ bits equal (where $k = 1$, by no other choice), is basically the probability of either to start with an $1$ or $0$. You do not care if it is a $0$ or $1$, you care if the $k$ bits are the same. That why it should be $1$.

Comment: @ÁlvaroRodrigo The OP is asking about two strings, not about one. If I hand you two random strings the probability that they start THE SAME WAY is 1/2.